# How to flowplayer play while a mp4 file is buffering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer

It always play only when mp4 is fully loaded, i would like to it playing while video is buffering, it's possible to do?

thanks.

Comment: post your flowplayer settings.. it would be helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use flowplayer with those settings and the video starts while it buffers

```
           flowplayer("player", {

                  // our Flash component
                 src: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf",
                     // we need at least this Flash version
                      version: [9, 115],
                   // older versions will see a custom message
                     onFail: function()  {
                      document.getElementById("info").innerHTML =
                     "You need the latest Flash version to see MP4 movies. " +
                        "Your version is " + this.getVersion();                           
                        }
                    // here is our third argument which is the Flowplayer configuration
                   },
                     {
                    clip: {
                            url: "<?php echo($fileName); ?>",
                            autoPlay: false,
                            autoBuffering: true
                        }
                      });
```

I think that "autoBuffering" is what you are looking for